# Calculate variance of period-to-period change of Markov chain given transition matrix.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, variance

In the process of working on a project, I am faced with the following question:

let us say our transition matrix $P$ is given by:
\begin{bmatrix}
    P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & P_{1,3} & P_{1,4} \\
    P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & P_{2,3} & P_{2,4} \\
    P_{3,1} & P_{3,2} & P_{3,3} & P_{3,4} \\
    P_{4,1} & P_{4,2} & P_{4,3} & P_{4,4}
  \end{bmatrix}
Where each state in our state space corresponds to a log level of income in the following vector: \begin{bmatrix}
 a & b & c&d \\
\end{bmatrix}
i.e $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ are the four levels of income.

Given this info, what is the general process of finding the variance of the period-to-period **change** in income over some $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ number of periods? Suppose it is known that the process begins in a given state (i.e begins in state 1 (income = $a$)). How might one begin this calculation? I'm confused how to approach this problem since we don't technically have a probability distribution for the initial state since we are simply assuming it starts in a given state.

Comment: Hey! What did you remove your post on finding the integer solutions of a system of equations. I spent quite some time on it and it is not correct to delete the work of someone who helped you for free. I note down your name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your initial state is definitely state $1$, then you *do* have a probability distribution over the initial state, $\ X_0\ $, namely,
$$
P\big(X_0=i\big)=\cases{1&if $\ i=1\ $,\\
0&otherwise,}
$$
which, for the purposes of calculating subsequent state probability distributions, is used in the form of the probability row vector $\ \pi_0^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\ $. After $\ n\ $ periods, the state probability distribution will be
$$
\pi_n^T=\pi_0^TP^n\ .
$$
If $\ \alpha=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}\ $ is the column vector of incomes, and $\ \beta=$$\,\begin{bmatrix}0\\(b-a)^2\\(c-a)^2\\(d-a)^2\end{bmatrix}\ $ the column vector of squared income changes, then the mean change in income over the first $\ n\ $ periods is
$$
\pi_n^T\alpha-a\ ,
$$
and the variance is
$$
\pi_n^T\beta-\big(\pi_n^T\alpha-a\big)^2\ .
$$

Comment: Are you sure that $\beta$ in the final calculation shouldn't be replaced with a column vector that instead represents the mean change in income squared (instead of simply income squared)? If not, would you mind saying a little bit more about where that last expression is coming from

Comment: Yes, the entries of $\ \beta\ $ should be the squares of the *changes* of income, not the squares of the incomes themselves.  Thank you for picking up the error, which I've now fixed.

Comment: No, it must be non-negative.   It's just a version of [the identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition)
$$
\text{Var}(X)=E\big[X^2\big]-E[X]^2\ .
$$